# Unity3D casting ray from the middle of the screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, screen, raycasting

I want to cast ray from middle of the screen now I do it by using mouse and set the mouse in the middle but it can causes bugs. I use:

```
ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
```

What should I use instead?

Comment: *"but it can causes bug*" care to explain what bugs?

Comment: I used to turn off visibility of cursor but it appears again for no reason. It's probably my fault.

Comment: *"It's probably my fault."*, a very valuable lesson for any programmer. Bugs are rarely the fault of the libraries/api's being used but are typically the operator of the keyboard in front of you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience I found that a Debug Ray (a ray which shows up in the Editor's Scene view) is a great help when working with Rays.

```
Vector3 rayOrigin = new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0f); // center of the screen
float rayLength = 500f;

// actual Ray
Ray ray = Camera.main.ViewportPointToRay(rayOrigin);

// debug Ray
Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * rayLength, Color.red);

RaycastHit hit;
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, rayLength))
{
    // our Ray intersected a collider
}
```

The Debug Ray is only available in the Scene view, while the game is running. If you want to draw a line in-game, look into [LineRenderer](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.html).

Comment: It should cast red ray from middle of my screen, yes?

Comment: Ok I thought it will be visible in Game view but it's not.
Thank you so much by the way :)

Comment: The Debug Ray is only available in the Scene view, while the game is running. If you want to draw a line in-game, look into LineRenderer http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.html